# Concatenation of two columns into one rounds float

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two DataFrames I want to concat. Both have the same column and they are of different dtypes. One is float, the other is a string. I want to concat these columns while keeping the granularity of the float column. See below for an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Row1':124.028125},orient='index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Row2':'Hello'},orient='index')
df_ = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

The `df_` variable is displayed as

```
df_
            0
Row1  124.0281
Row2     Hello
```

Basically how can I concat these while keeping 124.028125 as the value for Row1?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is not lost, it is just not displayed for the sake of clarity.

If one access

```
df_[0]['Row1']
```

one gets

```
124.028125
```

Comment: `pd.set_option('display.precision',10)` will changed the display precision so it prints out the whole `124.028125`

Comment: I knew this before and just forget. I did df.ix[0] and saw there was still no precision, so I assumed that it had somehow cut off the precision. Dumb, sorry!